# Pandas: Remove duplicate row pairs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I have following DataFrame in Py pandas

```
    source  target  value   type
0   10  1200    0.500   Undirected
1   13  3333    0.600   Undirected
2   10  1200    0.500   Undirected
3   15  2300    0.350   Undirected
4   18  5300    0.250   Undirected
5   17  2300    0.100   Undirected
6   13  3333    0.600   Undirected
```

1. I like to remove every row that is a duplicate (appears twice or
   more). In this case, the row with the *Index 0* and *Index 2* and
   *Index 1* and *Index 6* should be identified as a duplicates so that we only keep one of those entries.
2. How can I show duplicates of source and target? I like to cross-check if "value" is truly always identical.

Comment: just use `.drop_duplicates()` and `.duplicated()`

Answer (score 6):

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text="""    source  target  value   type
0   10  1200    0.500   Undirected
1   13  3333    0.600   Undirected
2   10  1200    0.500   Undirected
3   15  2300    0.350   Undirected
4   18  5300    0.250   Undirected
5   17  2300    0.100   Undirected
6   13  3333    0.600   Undirected"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), delim_whitespace=True, index_col=[0])
```

#### Solution

```
print df[df.duplicated()]

   source  target  value        type
2      10    1200    0.5  Undirected
6      13    3333    0.6  Undirected

print df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)

   source  target  value        type
3      15    2300   0.35  Undirected
4      18    5300   0.25  Undirected
5      17    2300   0.10  Undirected
```

#### Explanation

`df.duplicated()` returns boolean mask on what was duplicated

`df.drop_duplicates()` drops the duplicated rows

`keep=False` specifies to drop all rows that have been duplicated as opposed to keeping the first or last of the duplicated rows. [pandas drop duplicates: documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)

Comment: The OP wants to drop any values that are duplicates not to just remove the additional duplicate values

Comment: @EdChum thx, fixed it.  added `keep=False` to `drop_duplicates`